# Laravel 5.4: fetching data from url with no parameter

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have noticed a strange behaviour while pulling data in my view from the controller:

Lets say i have this route defined in my routes(web.php):

```
Route::get('user/getPageContent/{id}', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@getPageContent', 'as'=>'user.pagecontent']);
```

Now in my DashboardController, i have the function that returns the json:

```
public function getPageContent($id) 
{
    $content_model = new Content();
    $content = $content_model->getContent($id);
    $response = response()->json($content);

    return $response;
}
```

and to pull this in my view, i use Jquery $.get method:

```
$.get('user/getPageContent/'+id, function(response){
    //logic goes here
});
```

this works well. now if i create the same functionality for a url with no parameter, i do not get a response: i create the route as a get request:

```
Route::get('user/getAssessmentPage', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@getAssessmentPage', 'as'=>'user.assessmentpage']);
```

define the function in the controller:

```
public function getAssessmentPage()
{
    $content= Assessment_Page::all();
    $response = response()->json($content);

    return $response;
}
```

and try to access it in my view:

```
$.get('user/getAssessmentPage', function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

but i do not get a response. no response, no error in the console, nothing. so my question is, for url's with no parameters as shown, what would be the way to go to pulling the data?

should also mention i've even given the `.load` method a try but still no response.

Comment: does the call get through correctly? Maybe you can try to Log::info('something') in your controller action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was in my routes. this is how they were originally structured:

```
Route::resource('user', 'Users\DashboardController');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('user', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@index', 'as'=>'user.layout']);
    Route::get('user/displayMenuItems', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@displayMenuItems', 'as'=>'user.menuitems']);
    Route::get('user/getSubChapterContent/{id}', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@getSubChapterContent', 'as'=>'user.subchaptercontent']);
    Route::get('user/getPageContent/{id}', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@getPageContent', 'as'=>'user.pagecontent']);
    Route::get('user/getQuiz/{chapter_id}', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@getQuiz', 'as'=>'user.quiz']);
    Route::get('user/getCorrectChoice/{question_id}',['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@getCorrectChoice', 'as'=>'user.getanswer'] );
    Route::post('user/logChapterQuizes', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@logChapterQuizes', 'as'=>'user.logquiz']);
    Route::get('user/getAssessmentPage', ['uses'=>'Users\DashboardController@getAssessmentPage', 'as'=>'user.getAssessmentPage']);    
});
```

but after moving the `Route::resource('user', 'Users\DashboardController')` below the `Route::group`, i can now get the response.

The order of routes matters.

was fortunate enough to get the answer from laracasts. see this thread:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-fetching-data-from-url-with-no-parameter